# Python readlines() function ignores line written by program

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to read lines and check whether an specific number is in it, but when reading and printing the list with the lines I can't get the 1st line where my testing string was written by the same program:

Code I use to write stuff on the file:

```
with open('db.txt', 'a') as f:
     f.write(f'Request's channel id from guild {guild.id}:{request_channel_id} \n')
```

and the code I'm using to read the files and check the lines is:

```
with open('db.txt', 'r') as f:
        index = 0
        for line in f:
            index += 1
            if str(message.guild.id) in line or str(message.channel.id) in line:
                break

        content = f.readlines()
        print(content)
        content = content[index]
        content.strip(":")
```

The second block of code is returning: [] and empty list even though I opened it and the line is there. But, when I write directly at the file with my keyboard the code "sees" the random stuff I wrote.

.txt file content:

```
Id do canal de request servidor 833434062248869899: 888273958263222332
a.a

all
a
a
a
a
```

Error:

```
['a.a\n', '\n', 'all\n', 'a\n', 'a\n', 'a\n', 'a']
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\desktop\gabriel\codando\music_bot\main.py", line 48, in on_message
    request_channel_id = int(content[1])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Show output and error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: The line `f.write(f'Request's channel id from guild {guild.id}:{request_channel_id} \n')`should give a syntax error, replace it with `f.write(f'Request\'s channel id from guild {guild.id}:{request_channel_id} \n')`

Comment: A file object remembers where it read or wrote last. When you call "f.readlines()" it only reads and returns the lines **after** the line which fulfilled the if-condition. Solution: Just reuse the already read "line" after the for-loop instead of calling "readlines".

Comment: I didn't know about the file object remembering the lines it read/wrote, but it worked. Thank you! :))

And about the " \' " that may cause error, it's not wrote like that in the original, I translated from portuguese to give a better idea of the stuff I was trying to wrote.